# How to show the 'has-error' class on an invalid field in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Given:

```
<div class="form-group" [fieldValidity]="email">
  <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
  <input [(ngModel)]="model.email" ngControl="email" required>
</div>
```

And my custom [fieldValidity] directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from 'angular2/core';
import {NgControlName} from 'angular2/common';
@Directive({
  selector: '[fieldValidity]'
})
export class FieldValidityDirective {
  private el: HTMLElement;
  @Input('fieldValidity') field: NgControlName;
  constructor(el: ElementRef) { 
    this.el = el.nativeElement;
  }
  private _onValidityChange(value: string) {
    //TODO test field.valid || field.pristine
    if (?) { 
      this.el.classList.remove('has-error');
    } else {
      this.el.classList.add('has-error');
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get subscribe to the field.valid && field .pristine values to show the error? (I've marked it with 'TODO' below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also implement the `ngDoCheck` method to check the validity:

```
ngDoCheck(value: string) {
  if (field.valid || field.pristine) { 
    this.el.classList.remove('has-error');
  } else {
    this.el.classList.add('has-error');
  }
}
```

That said you could implement a wrapping component that leverages `ngClass` directly on the element. Something like that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'field',
  template: `
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm" [ngClass]="{'has-error':state && !state.valid}">
      <label for="for" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{label}}</label>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <!-- Input, textarea or select -->
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        <span *ngIf="state && !state.valid" class="help-block text-danger">
          <span *ngIf="state.errors.required">The field is required</span>
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
`
})
export class FormFieldComponent {
  @Input()
  label: string;

  @Input()
  state: Control;
}
```

You can even go further by directly referencing the control from the `ng-content` using the `@ContentChild` decorator:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class FormFieldComponent {
  @Input()
  label: string;

  @ContentChild(NgFormControl) state;

  (...)
}
```

This way you would be able to define your input this way with `ngFormControl` (would also work with `ngControl`):

```
<form [ngFormModel]="companyForm">
  <field label="Name">
    <input [ngFormControl]="companyForm.controls.name" 
           [(ngModel)]="company.name"/>
  </field>
</form>
```

See this article for more details (section "Form component for fields"):

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

Comment: Have implemented the ngDoCheck solution! If anyone is confused as to how ngDoCheck() get's called. Angular uses background magic to automatically call ngDoCheck, when inputs for the directive are changed. so as long as you use @input annotation you should be fine.

Answer (score 7):

An easy way is to use the data-driven approach with the [ngClass] directive as follows

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div [ngClass]="{'has-error': form.controls['description'].invalid}">
            <input type="text" formControlName="description" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="description">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Component:

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  private form: FormGroup;
  private description: string;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      description: new FormControl('')
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make your validation check a validator like shown in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/FormBuilder-class.html or https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html and use a directive like below to set your custom class when Angular sets the `ng-invalid` class, or just use the `ng-invalid` class Angular already sets instead of introducing a new one.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input'
})
export class AddClass {
  @HostBinding('class.has-error')
  hasError:boolean = false;

  @Input('class') classes;
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.hasError = classes.split(' ').indexOf('ng-invalid') >= 0);
  }
}
```

You need to add `AddClass` directive to `directives: [AddClass]` of the component where you want to use it.