# Angular - FormGroup Display json errors from server Rest Api

Tags: json, rest, angular, angular2-forms

I have a REST API server with the php framework Symfony that return this kinds of messages :

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Validation Failed",
  "errors": {
    "children": {
      "email": {
        "errors": [
          "This address mail is already used."
        ]
      },
      "name": {
        "errors": [
          "This name is too short."
        ]
      },
      "password": []
    }
  }
}
```

And on the front side with Angular FormGroup i have this code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { RegisterService } from './register.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-authentication',
  templateUrl: './authentication.component.html',
})
export class AuthenticationComponent {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    error: string = '';

    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder, 
        private registerService: RegisterService, 
        private router: Router
    ) {
        this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
            'name': ['', Validators.required],
            'email': ['', Validators.required],
            'password': ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.authenticationService
            .authenticate(this.loginForm.value)
            .subscribe(
                data => { 
                    localStorage.setItem('id_token', data.token);
                    this.router.navigate(['post']); 
                },
                error 
                => 
                // Do something
                // Display server json errors in the corresponding fields
            );
    }
}
```

How can I get each error message from REST API and display under the corresponding field ?

Thanks you for your help

Comment: Is that the exact JSON? Just wondering about the duplicate `name`, which other is an empty array and other is an object...?

Comment: This json is exact now. I change the duplicate 'name' for 'password' :).

Comment: Okay, great. But password is a array like that? It does not look like: `"password": {"errors":[]}`? Just asking because this is important if we'd want to loop that data :)

Comment: No just array empty for correct field. I use FosrestBundle of symfony, that returns empty array when the field is correct.

Comment: Okay, just wanted to make sure. I'll now take a look at your code and see if we cannot come up with something :)

Comment: you have something?

Answer (score 1):

Lazy way of doing is to fetch the error attribute manually for each field(email, name).

```
emailError : string = '';
nameError : string = '';

onSubmit() {
        this.authenticationService
            .authenticate(this.loginForm.value)
            .subscribe(
                data => {                        
                    localStorage.setItem('id_token', data.token);
                    this.router.navigate(['post']); 
                },
                (error : any) => {
                let errorData = error.json();
                if(errorData.children.email.errors.length > 0){
                     this.emailError = errorData.children.email.errors[0];
                }
                if(errorData.children.name.errors.length > 0)){
                     this.nameError = errorData.children.name.errors[0];
                }
              }
            );
    }
```

html code to counter errors in form

```
<input formControlName="name" />
<span *ngIf="nameError != ''">{{nameError}}</span>     // error from back end
<div *ngIf="loginForm.controls['name'].hasError('required')">Please enter name</div> // form error in frontend
```

Alternatively you can do it using `ngClass`

```
<div [ngClass]="{'has-error': loginForm.controls['name'].invalid}">
  <input formControlName="name" />
</div>
```

Reference : [How to show the 'has-error' class on an invalid field in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102343/how-to-show-the-has-error-class-on-an-invalid-field-in-angular-2)

Comment: And i put {{nameError}} and {{emailError}} under the fields ?

Comment: Yes. that should be enough unless you have multiple error messages returned against each field.

Comment: How can i add class "has-error" on the near "form-group" of the field ?

Comment: Ah! 'has-error' is for form validation in the front end. In your case you are displaying errors from back end. Any ways I will update my answer for form validation.

Comment: Yes i display errors from back-end in front-end, so i want insert has-error to color font in red.

Comment: @kaneda I think you did not understand my comment. 'has-error' is related to form error in the frontend. Do not mix up that with backend error.

Comment: @kaneda If you want to display the backend error in red color then do this `<span style="color:red" *ngIf="nameError != ''">{{nameError}}</span>`

Comment: I understand, but with your previous style, only the error is in red color and not the field. So i want to use <div class="has-error"><input type="email" name="email" /><span *ngIf="nameError != ''">{{nameError}}</span></div>.
So like that the both, field and message error are in red.

Comment: Since your problem is with displaying back end error, you cannot take control of form in this way. Please understand the difference between front end (form error) and backend error.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not much different than Amit's, but here we are not setting values longhand in the same manner, but instead storing the errors in an object. This could probably be refined some more ;)

```
formErrors = {}; // object to store error messages

 ...
(error : any) => {
    // get the nested errors
    let errorData = error.json().errors.children;
    // iterate the keys in errors
    for(let key in errorData) {
      // if key has nested "errors", get and set the error message, else set null
      errorData[key].errors ? this.formErrors[key]=errorData[key].errors[0] : this.formErrors[key] = null
    }
}
```

and then in your template you would just show the error messages if they exist:

```
<label>Name</label>
<input formControlName="name" />
<small *ngIf="formErrors.name">{{formErrors.name}}</small>

<label>Email</label>
<input formControlName="email" />
<small *ngIf="formErrors.email">{{formErrors.email}}</small>

<label>Password</label>
<input formControlName="password" />
<small *ngIf="formErrors.password">{{formErrors.password}}</small>
```

Remember to reset the `formErrors` object after each round, so you have the updated values :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response code for each kind of error if the format of the array will be different for unique errors.

`error => {
   if (error.code=="400"){this.error = error.errors.children.email.errors[0];}
   if (error.code=="412"){...}
 }`

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking, this is my answer, (I just applied this in angular 6)

Create a map like this

`errors= new Map<string, string>();`

Then, in the view check like this

```
  <div *ngIf="errors.has('name')"> {{errors.has('name') ? errors.get('name') : ''}} </div>
```

So lets say you get a json from server like this

```
 {
   "errors": [
              {
                "field": "username",
                "message": "Corresponding message"
              },
              {
                "field": "password",
                 "message": "Corresponding message for password"
              }
    ]
 }
```

You could create a method like this

```
 this.yourService.add(this.user).subscribe(response => {
      // response was 200 ok, so no errors here
   },
   (json) => {
        for( let entry of json.errors )  {
            this.errors.set(entry.field, entry.message);
          }
   });
```

Or even should be more easy if server already provides you a Map (of course you have to create the corresponding classes in typescript to make json serialization/deserialization).

I hope this helps.